# Yahoo Hosting: Custom Error Pages (IE)

Tags: web-server, hosting, http-status-code-404

So one of my clients uses Yahoo Hosting in a shared environment. Absolutely horrible, can't even upload a .htaccess file.

They have an option where you can setup custom error pages by uploading a a html file into the main directory with a specific name (ie 404 is e404.html). The problem is Internet Explorer does not redirect to this custom error page, but all other tested browsers do (ie: google chrome, safari). http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/smallbusiness/webhosting/editors/editors-16.html

**In Internet Explorer (tested ie7-ie9) the user is not redirected to this custom error page. Instead they are showen a IE 404 error page.**

So how does this error page redirect work? and how can I get IE to work with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are they're not being redirected.

Internet Explorer will not display error pages if they're under 512 bytes (on the idea that it's probably not a useful message if it's that short, I suppose). Add a long `<!-- HTML comment -->` (a couple hundred characters worth of lorem ipsum, perhaps) and see if your custom message starts showing up.

Comment: You can also turn off IE Friendly Error Messages in IE.  You can also use the developer tools in IE or any browser for that matter and run a network trace to see the exact HTTP response from the server.

Comment: @BrentPabst turning off the IE friendly error message is just a client side solution so not very helpful. Never used the dev tools to run a network trace though so that's helpful info for the future.

Comment: The IE error page size was the issue. I have never, ever, ever, heard of that being an issue before. The error page was very small too because it was just a meta redirect. So I added some commented out lorum ipsum and it works now. Thanks

Comment: @mcflause I simply mentioned it as that is the first thing I do to IE on my workstation so I always get the precise error message, since after all it was a client issue not displaying the full error.